# ValueError: On entry to ZGEHD2 parameter number 2 had an illegal value

Tags: python, python-3.6, lapack, eigenvalue, eigenvector

I'm using python to solve an eigenvalue problem when this error occurs. The version I'm using is install by anaconda: 3.6.3 |Intel Corporation.

The line where the error occurs is(Corre is the matrix I'm diagonalizing):

```
[fk, mode] = linalg.eig(Corre)
```

The message is:

> File "/Users/zhanwang/anaconda/envs/intelpy3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/linalg/decomp.py", line 209, in eig
>   overwrite_a=overwrite_a)
>
> ValueError: On entry to ZGEHD2 parameter number 2 had an illegal value

This error shows up occasionally only for some matrix (e.g. matrix with dimension 2304 or 6400) but not for matrix with other larger or smaller dimensions.
So I'm wondering what does this message tell me?

Comment: This might or might not be related: https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/804, maybe you could try a more recent (or older) version of numpy, to see if it helps.